# Two characters look alike but evaluate as different. How can I track down the explicit difference?

Tags: r, string, character-encoding

I have two srings `s` and `t` that look exactly identical when I print them, but when I compare them with `==`, R outputs `FALSE`. I have tracked down the difference to character number 26 in the two strings, and... See for yourselves:

```
> substring(s, 26, 26)
[1] "–"
> substring(t, 26, 26)
[1] "–"
> substring(s, 26, 26) == substring(t, 26, 26)
[1] FALSE
> substring(s, 26, 26) == "-"
[1] FALSE
> substring(t, 26, 26) == "-"
[1] FALSE
```

where on the last two lines, I entered the dash manually from my keyboard. Clearly these are three different dashes, but what's the difference? Which is which?

This problem has probably arisen from several people copy-pasting on different computers between different editions of MS Word and Excel, and then finally me reading it in to R via a `.csv` file.

Specifically, can I find the codepoints (or something similar) of these two mysterious characters within R so that I can find out what the problem is?

Because it was asked for:

```
> s
[1] "Salmonid alfavirus (SAV) – Rutinemessig prøvetaking § 4, 1. ledd (avsnitt), § 4, 2. ledd (avsnitt) & §13, 1. ledd (avsnitt)."
> t
[1] "Salmonid alfavirus (SAV) – Rutinemessig prøvetaking § 4, 1. ledd (avsnitt), § 4, 2. ledd (avsnitt) & §13, 1. ledd (avsnitt)."
```

That dash after `(SAV)` is character number 26, the one in question.

**Edit:** After the answers told me about `charToRaw()`, I decided to try that. Here are the results:

```
> charToRaw(substring(t, 26, 26))
[1] 96
> charToRaw(substring(s, 26, 26))
[1] 96
> substring(s, 26, 26) == substring(t, 26, 26)
[1] FALSE
```

Now I am even more stumped. The characters have the same codepoint but are still unequal? What is going on here?

**New development:**
I put the two characters into their own variables, because I got tired of substringing all the time. Then I compared each of them to a copy-pasted version of the other:

```
> a = substring(s, 26, 26)
> b = substring(t, 26, 26)
> a == b
[1] FALSE
> a
[1] "–"
> b
[1] "–"
> a == "–"
[1] FALSE
> b == "–"
[1] TRUE
```

So somehow, copy-pasting the output from `> a` will give a character that is considered equal to `b`. I am sorry, but this also means that since this post is made up of copy-pasted code, the dashes that appear in this post are probably actually identical.

Comment: Please show what is `s` and `t`.  May be the symbols are different.

Comment: You need to add s and t string in your question. So, we can see whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use R myself, but you can find instructions to get the ascii codes in R [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/ascii-code-table-in-r/).

Using copy-paste from your question and Python, I find that "-" in both your strings is actually 3 characters:

```
for l in "AV) – Rut":  #copy-pasted from the question
   print(l, ord(l))
```

> ('A', 65) 
>   ('V', 86) (')', 41) (' ', 32) ('\xe2', 226) ('\x80', 128)
>   ('\x93', 147) (' ', 32) ('R', 82) ('u', 117) ('t', 116)

Both your versions give the same answer, which is very strange. But both differ from the regular dash:

```
for l in "-":  # With the normal dash typed myself
  print(l, ord(l))
```

> ('-', 45)

You'll find [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) the characters corresponding to  ('\xe2', 226) ('\x80', 128) ('\x93', 147)

Comment: According to the `asc()` function in your link (and the `charToRaw()` function they use applied directly) they are equal. Yet they still refuse to evaluate as equal according to `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and look up the hex values in character code tables which you can find via google.

```
charToRaw("hello")
## [1] 68 65 6c 6c 6f
```

Comment: I saw `charToRaw()` in the other answer as well. Both dashes give `96` as a result (while a keyboard dash gives `2d`), but they still refuse to be equal according to `==`.

Comment: You could also try `utf8ToInt`

Answer (score 1):

```
s <- "Salmonid alfavirus (SAV) – Rutinemessig prøvetaking § 4, 1. ledd (avsnitt), § 4, 2. ledd (avsnitt) & §13, 1. ledd (avsnitt)."

t <- "Salmonid alfavirus (SAV) – Rutinemessig prøvetaking § 4, 1. ledd (avsnitt), § 4, 2. ledd (avsnitt) & §13, 1. ledd (avsnitt)."

substring(s, 26, 26) == substring(t, 26, 26)
#[1] TRUE

substring(s, 26, 26)
#[1] "–"

substring(t, 26, 26)
#[1] "–"

## comparing dash in string with regular dash on keyboard
substring(s, 26, 26) == "-"
#[1] FALSE

substring(t, 26, 26) == "-"
#[1] FALSE
```

The dash from string and regular dash seems to be different. Lets check their hex values with ASCii codes:

```
asc <- function(x) {strtoi(charToRaw(x),16L)}

asc(substring(s, 26, 26))
#[1] 226 128 147

asc("-")
#[1] 45
```

So, I think its not surprise that the dash from string and regular dash does not result TRUE when compared.

Comment: Yeah, I was pretty certain from the beginning that the regular dash was different. If you look closely you can see that it is shorter. Also, I realised that copy-pasting makes the two mysterious dashes actually equal, so one of them I am unable to post here for you to play with. That's why your substring test evaluates to `TRUE`.